# Want incremental update in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

[image]

If ItemCode, Color, Size, Rack, Rack1 match then the Num column needs to take incremental values instead of NULL. This means that for the highlighted rows it needs to take values `1` and `2` and for others (non-repeated) records it needs to take the value `1`.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Do you need incremental only when ALL the columns are equal ?

Comment: Yes, Want incremental when all column equal.

Comment: Please provide your expected result set in table data..

Comment: Try my Updated Answer. Hope you don't have PK in your table.

Comment: I have given 2 solutions. Please check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table Schema:

```
 CREATE TABLE Items
    (
        ItemCode VARCHAR(10),
        Color INT,
        Size VARCHAR(10),
        Rack VARCHAR(10),
        RACK1 INT,
        NUM INT
    )
```

Data:

```
INSERT INTO Items VALUES
('LY-164', 1, 'L', 'LT', 74, NULL),
('LY-164', 1, 'M', 'LT', 75, NULL),
('LY-164', 1, 'XL', 'LT', 67, NULL),
('LY-164', 1, 'XXL', 'LT', 70, NULL),
('LY-178', 1, 'L', 'LT', 104, NULL),
('LY-178', 1, 'L', 'LT', 109, NULL),
('LY-178', 1, 'M', 'LT', 122, NULL),
('LY-178', 1, 'M', 'LT', 122, NULL),
('LY-178', 1, 'XL', 'LT', 108, NULL),
('LY-178', 1, 'XL', 'LT', 109, NULL),
('LY-178', 1, 'XXL', 'LT', 108, NULL)
```

If you don't have Primary Key in your table you may use this. Here I am inserting first then deleting the null values.

```
; WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ItemCode, Color, Size, Rack, Rack1
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemCode, Color, Size, Rack, Rack1 ORDER BY ItemCode, Color, Size, Rack, Rack1) AS RN
    FROM Items
) 
INSERT INTO Items
SELECT * FROM CTE

DELETE FROM Items WHERE NUM IS NULL

SELECT * FROM Items
```

This is another approach (Quirky Update, one of the black magic in SQL)

```
DECLARE @ItemCode VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @Color INT
DECLARE @Size VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @Rack VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @RACK1 INT
DECLARE @NUM INT = 1

UPDATE A
SET
@NUM = IIF(@ItemCode IS NULL OR @ItemCode <> A.ItemCode OR @Color <> A.Color OR @Size <> A.Size OR @Rack <> A.Rack OR @RACK1 <> A.RACK1, 1, @Num + 1),
@ItemCode = A.ItemCode,
@Color = A.Color,
@Size = A.Size,
@Rack = A.Rack,
@RACK1 = A.RACK1,
A.Num = @NUM
FROM Items A

SELECT * FROM Items
```

Answer

```
LY-164  1   L   LT  74  1
LY-164  1   M   LT  75  1
LY-164  1   XL  LT  67  1
LY-164  1   XXL LT  70  1
LY-178  1   L   LT  104 1
LY-178  1   L   LT  109 1
LY-178  1   M   LT  122 1
LY-178  1   M   LT  122 2
LY-178  1   XL  LT  108 1
LY-178  1   XL  LT  109 1
LY-178  1   XXL LT  108 1
```

Comment: I dont see anything specific to `SQL SERVER 2012+` should work with `SQL SERVER 2008` as well